# How does inheritance of FontSize in silverlight tree work?

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties

If I have a `ChildWindow` in Silverlight I can apply the `FontSizeProperty` and it is inherited by child items.

```
<controls:ChildWindow FontSize="14">

     <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Content="Hello">
          <TextBlock Content="World">
     </StackPanel>

</controls:ChildWindow>
```

Now that's fine if you want the whole page to have the same font size, but I want to do something like this and have inheritance in smaller blocks:

```
<controls:ChildWindow>

     <StackPanel FontSize="14">
          <TextBlock Content="Hello">
          <TextBlock Content="World">
     </StackPanel>

     <StackPanel FontSize="10">
          <TextBlock Content="Hello">
          <TextBlock Content="World">
     </StackPanel>

</controls:ChildWindow>
```

This doesn't compile. Is there any way i can achieve this pattern in Silverlight without having to define a style for `StackPanel` (I think that would work).

Are there any other containers that let me set `FontSize` for its descendants - or can I write one that would?

I want to easily set fontsize to be larger for certain `StackPanels`. I don't want to resort to styles because its very specialized and I won't need to reuse the style elsewhere.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap each `StackPanel` in a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28VS.95%29.aspx), which does implement `FontSize`.

Comment: thanks! i got close with ContentPresenter, but this is what I was needing